# YQL finance data JSON format for use with highcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, highcharts, yql

Im using jQuery and highcharts.js to build a single line chart on my webpage that shows historical financial data for whatever company the user requests. I have been playing around with YQL and used this statement to retrieve some quotes in JSON format:

select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "AAPL" and startDate = "2013-02-01" and endDate = "2013-02-25"

Heres a link to the YQL console with my query:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22AAPL%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222013-02-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222013-02-25%22

It returns a bunch of info about execution-start-time and exection-end-time and then at the end it gives me the quotes im after:

```
"results": {
"quote": [
{
 "date": "2013-02-25",
 "Date": "2013-02-25",
 "Open": "453.85",
 "High": "455.12",
 "Low": "442.57",
 "Close": "442.80",
 "Volume": "13306400",
 "Adj_Close": "442.80"
},
```

Im having trouble extracting the Close price information from the results, ive tried the following code but im having trouble.

```
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22AAPL%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222013-02-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222013-02-25%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=cbfunc', function(data){

    console.log(data);

    var close = data.query.results.quote.close;
    document.write(close);

})
```

Can somebody tell me where im going wrong as I am new to jquery, yql and json.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the returned quote object is an array ?
Have you tried

```
var close = data.query.results.quote[0].Close;
document.write(close);
```

If not, try setting a breakpoint on that line and examine the data object (e.g. in firebug).

Comment: I have tried using firebug but its still not working. It is showing that: query: Object {count=16} results: Object {quote=[16]} quote 0: Object { date="2013-02-25", Date="2013-02-25", Open="453.85", more...} this is the same for all 16 quotes